# Is the block of if statement in DOSBox different than in Windows CMD?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, dosbox

I made a batch file in Windows Command Prompt (CMD) and it worked.

Considering that DOSBox is the same as CMD, I just ran the same code and it did not work. And I noticed that there could be some difference as stated in [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dosbox+batch-file).

This is the batch file content:

```
:: Hide commands
@echo off

:: Verbose usage
if "%1"=="" (
    echo Usage: tpc [file]
    echo file    a Turbo Pascal file
    goto eof
)

set file=%1
c:\tpwdb\bin\tpc %file%

echo.

echo Execute with %file%

:eof
```

In CMD it produced:

```
>tpc
Usage: tpc [file]
file    a Turbo Pascal file

>tpc 02\hellow.pas
This version of c:\tpwdb\bin\TPC.EXE is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.

Execute with 02\hellow.pas
```

But in DOSBox it produced:

```
>tpc
Illegal command: (.
Usage: tpc [file]
file    a Turbo Pascal file

>tpc 02\hellow.pas
Usage: tpc [file]
file    a Turbo Pascal file
```

Which shows that it did not recognize if block `( )` and when there was an argument passed, it still execute the block but did not show message `Illegal command: (.`.

Comment: MS-DOS (`COMMAND.COM`) did not support parenthesised code blocks, such are only possible in the Windows Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`)...

Comment: Which version of MS-DOS did you use to test against?

Comment: I think @aschipfl is right, I use Windows Command Prompt and not MS-DOS.

Comment: It was Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.885], @melpomene.

Comment: OK, that is not DOS at all.

Comment: Can I change the title for correcting it that it was Windows Command Prompt and not MS-DOS, @melpomene?

Comment: [Are the Command Prompt and MS-DOS the same thing?](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386) The answer is no. They have very different syntax